# Maintain sessions in Laravel 4

Tags: session, laravel

I don't know how to maintain and work with sessions. As I am a newbie in Laravel 4.

I have created a table as follows:

```
class Sessions extends Migration 
{
Schema::create('sessions', function($table)
{
    $table->string('id')->unique();
    $table->text('payload');
    $table->integer('last_activity');
});
}
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1: `php artisan session:table`

Step 2: `composer dump-autoload`

Step 3: `php artisan migrate`

if you have setup multiple environment on your laravel app then

`php artisan migrate --env=ENVIRONMENT_NAME`

Step 4: Change the default driver on `/app/config/session.php` to

```
'driver'=>'database',
```

if you have multiple Databases configured on your L4 app, then configure the connection on
`/app/config/session.php`

```
'connection'=>CONNECTION_NAME
```

Comment: Sir,after setting connection,how to maintain sessions?? Please revert back

Comment: Also uploading multiple files is not part of this post. Please raise a separate question for that, so that you get help from multiple people. I will look into that as well.

Comment: sure sir I m rising a new question